# Pdf.js basic guide/tutorial to build a viewer with zoom pan and scroll

Tags: scroll, zooming, pdf.js, viewer, pan

I am  trying to build from scratch a minimalist Pdf.js viewer: I would just need zoom, pan and actual page number/overall pages number.
I am able to set the initial zoom so that the pdf is shown as I want at the beginning, i.e. it fits one of the two dimension of the available screen (for clarity in my code below I directly set the height property supposing the aspect ratio (height / width) of the document is higher than that of the available screen).
 Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
             height:100%; width:100%">
    <head>
       <title>PDF.js Learning</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78); margin: 0; padding: 0;
                 border: 0; height:100%; width:100%">
        <div style="position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
                    height:100%; width:100%">
            <canvas id="the-canvas" style="position: absolute; margin: 0;
                                           padding: 0; border: 0; top: 50%;
                                           left: 50%;
                                           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
            </canvas>
        </div>

        <!-- JQuery libraries -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Pdf.js libraries -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="build\pdf.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="web\compatibility.js></script>

        <script>
            var url = "your_PDF_url";

            // Asynchronous download PDF
            function openPdf () {
                PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function(pdf) {
                    return pdf.getPage(1);
                }).then(function(page) {

                    /* Get viewport (dimensions) and setting scale depending on 
                       the relative aspect ratio of the pdf and window*/

                       var desiredHeight = $(window).height(); //or width
                       var viewport = page.getViewport(1);
                       var scale = desiredHeight / viewport.height; //or width
                       viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                       // Get canvas#the-canvas
                       var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');

                       // Fetch canvas' 2d context
                       var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                       // Set dimensions to Canvas
                       canvas.height = viewport.height;
                       canvas.width = viewport.width;

                       // Prepare object needed by render method
                       var renderContext = {
                       canvasContext: context,
                       viewport: viewport
                       };

                       // Render PDF page
                       page.render(renderContext);
              });
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                (openPdf());
            });

            $(window).resize(function() {
                (openPdf());
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't find anywhere how I should do if I want to resize the pdf document or if I want to zoom it in and out:
should I reload the document and re-render? 
Should I only re-render it (as, if I haven't misunderstood, the pdf file once loaded, should be already available) with a new scale? 
Is there a less computation option than the 2 above?
I tried the first one (calling the PDFJS.getDocument() on resize) but it is really consuming and sometimes I get a bad rendering or no render at all.
Is there a reference for this and for pan somewhere? 
And how to show scroll bar, in the case of multiple pages documents, to change page? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Crosspost https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8133

Comment: @async5 Yes, I have posted almost the same question (without the code) also there because I don't know which were the best/right place (if any).